# Ignore click event on textbox

Tags: jquery

I am using the following syntax -

```
$("#tBox").on("input", function(event) {
    // do stuff
});
```

This works fine in Chrome and FireFox however in IE when you click on `tBox`, it fires the aforementioned event.

Is there a way to ignore if the event is triggered from a click?

I have done a quickwatch on the `event` for different types e.g. keyup, click, paste etc but cannot find any variable to say it has come from a click event (to then ignore).

Comment: Try event.preventDefault(); and return false; Not sure if I understood correctly

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6mapp846/2/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use preventDefault to prevent the default stuff that happens:

```
$("#tBox").on("click", function (event) {
event.preventDefault();
});
```

Not sure that im giving you the right answer...

Answer (score 0):

Try using `event.stopPropagation();` in your method. It should stop it from hitting any other events. eg:

```
$("#tBox").on("input", function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();

    // Do stuff
});
```